# Bootstrap Modal are Not Working at All

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple `<a>` tag with a button set to activate a modal. For some reason, it will not work. I have tried to initialize it manually, but I had no luck. I have tried to set the `href=` field to the modal id, but with no luck. This was working perfectly earlier this  week, then it just stopped. It redirects me to the top of my page. Any thoughts?

Modals

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-3" tabindex="-1" role="modal" aria-labelledby="modal-label-3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h4 id="modal-label-3" class="modal-title">Large Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row mb20">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium atque architecto quae ullam rem labore veritatis temporibus asperiores, ad eaque odit commodi inventore dolore perspiciatis, nam dicta est eos id quod excepturi.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 xs-box">
            <div class="box-services-a">
              <h3>Fast processing code</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis maiores repudiandae, accusantium reiciendis!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="box-services-a">
              <h3>Endless variations</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis maiores repudiandae, accusantium reiciendis!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-b" type="button">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-b" type="button">Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Section Calling It (Yes I am using a template. Its POLO V2)

```
<section>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-small jumbotron-border">
      <h3>Large Modal</h3>
      <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sagittis, sem quis lacinia faucibus, orci ipsum gravida tortor, vel interdum mi sapien ut justo. Nulla varius consequat magna, id molestievolutpat. </p>
      <a class="button color button-3d rounded effect icon-left" data-target="#modal-3" data-toggle="modal" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>Open Large Modal</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it's working fine, may be anything other causing problem https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/0kq4md55/

Comment: hey if there any problem please tell, the modal is working fine.

Comment: @MadanBhandari @Bhansa I figured it out. It was the way my div tags were in my `base.html` thanks for your help and your jsfiddle